# SSRS Expression - Find First Day of Week From Week value

Tags: reporting-services

I've got an SSRS report that returns unique login count to our VDI Pools broken down by week.
For example for January it would read:

```
     Week                # of Logins  
2015_JANUARY_WEEK_NO_1       3  
2015_JANUARY_WEEK_NO_2       49
```

I'm using the Week column to link to another report that'll display the selected week's logins so I have to get the first day of the selected week and the last day of the select week and pass them to the other report as parameters.

I know how to get pull the year and week # from the Week column.

```
=Mid(Fields!Week.Value,1,4)
```

gives me the year and 
                                                                                                  `=Trim(Mid(Fields!Week.Value,Len(Fields!Week.Value),Len(Fields!Week.Value)))`

gives me the week.

I found this T-SQL that works:

```
DECLARE @WeekNum INT
          , @YearNum char(4);

SELECT @WeekNum = 2 
     , @YearNum = 2015  
-- once you have the @WeekNum and @YearNum set, the following calculates the date range. 

SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + @YearNum) + (@WeekNum-1), 6) AS StartOfWeek;   
SELECT DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + @YearNum) + (@WeekNum-1), 5) AS EndOfWeek;
```

but I cannot figure out how to turn that into an expression that doesn't throw an error.

This is what I've got so far:

```
=DateAdd("w", DateDiff("w", 6, '1/1/' + (Mid(Fields!Week.Value,1,4))) + (Trim(Mid(Fields!Week.Value,Len(Fields!Week.Value),Len(Fields!Week.Value)))
- 1), 6)
```

and when I try to run the report in design view it returns an Expression expected error.

**Edit** 
Sorry, I guess I should've posted my original query that's populating the report. Here it is below:

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(20),UPPER(DATENAME(YEAR, Time)))
    +'_'+CONVERT(varchar(20),UPPER(DATENAME(MONTH, Time)))
    +'_WEEK_NO_'+CONVERT(varchar(10),(DAY(Time) 
    + (DATEPART(DW, DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, Time), 0))-1) -1)/7 + 1) as 'Week'
    , Count(DISTINCT SUBSTRING(ModuleAndEventText,LEN('User ') + 2
    , CHARINDEX(' requested', ModuleAndEventText) - LEN('User ') - 2)) as WeekCount
  FROM VE1_UserLogins
WHERE DesktopId = @Pool
AND ([Time] BETWEEN (@StartDate) and (DATEADD(ms, -1, @EndDate +1)))
GROUP BY Convert(varchar(20),UPPER(DATENAME(YEAR, Time)))
    +'_'+CONVERT(varchar(20),UPPER(DATENAME(MONTH, Time)))
    +'_WEEK_NO_'+CONVERT(varchar(10),(DAY(Time) 
    + (DATEPART(DW, DATEADD (MONTH, DATEDIFF (MONTH, 0, Time), 0))-1) -1)/7 + 1),YEAR(Time),MONTH(Time)
ORDER BY YEAR(Time), MONTH(Time), Week
```

Comment: What is your `Fields!Week.Value` value . What is it's data type ?

Comment: How is this `Mid(Fields!Week.Value,Len(Fields!Week.Value),Len(Fields!Week.Value))` will work as you are getting `Mid` from starting from it's end to the length of it is the length of the string

Comment: That confused me as well but when I tried `code`Mid(Fields!Week.Value,Len(Fields!Week.Value)-1,Len(Fields!Week.Value)) it was returning the underscore before the number.

Comment: what is value of the your `DATENAME` field

Comment: DATENAME is a built in SQL variable. It automatically turns 1 into January, 2 into February, etc.

Comment: Sorry I mean to say, What value does `Time`  field holds

Comment: Time holds the value of when the user logged in... eg. 2014-09-15 11:31:10.383

Comment: I have updated the answer, If it helps you please accept so question can be closed .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am assuming your `Fields!Week.Value` is `string` in `date` format like `MM/dd/yyyy` or something similar so if you want to get the start of that week `Sunday` as first day and `Saturday`  as last day and you want to get there date then you should use below expression,

For start of week,

```
  =DateAdd("d",1-  DatePart("w", CDate(Fields!WeekDate.Value)), CDate(Fields!WeekDate.Value))
```

For end of week,

```
=DateAdd("d", 7 - DatePart("w", CDate(Fields!WeekDate.Value)), CDate(Fields!WeekDate.Value))
```

### ----------

---

**UPDATE**
Now there are two ways to achieve what you want

1)Calculate start of week and end of week at the sql and get the result to directly display on repott

2) Get `time` field from the sql and set expression in the SSRS

For the first way to achieve you need to add these two lines in your select sql statement

```
    DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, MIN(Time))-1),MIN(Time)) AS 'StartOfWeek'
   ,DATEADD(dd, 7-(DATEPART(dw, MIN(Time))), MIN(Time)) AS 'EndOfWeek'
```

Second way to achieve is 
Update your `Sql` statement to get the date part and then include that date into the above given expression.
So for you your query you need to add,

```
        ,MIN(Time) AS WeekDate
```

Then you can use the above expression with using the incoming field `WeekDate` as input(I have updated the expression).

But, If you have no actual need for the `date` other than calculating the start and end of week then use the first method to get the data from the sql server as formatted.

Comment: The Fields!Week.Value is a string value that's exactly like I displayed the results. I've edited my post to include the query I used to generate the report.

Comment: this code starts the beginning of the week on sunday.  I had to add one day for it to start on Monday.